# Clicking to load the edit on a question doesn't reload the title

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, live-refresh

So an edit to the question is made and the edit includes a title change. When I click the little grey box that pops up, it loads the edit. When it's on a question and there is a change in title, should it not also load the new title? This is *especially* annoying when the *only* edit that was made was the title. Clicking the box loads... nothing new... why did I have to click the box again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Titles were not previously included with the realtime inline update of a post edit - the next deploy will add this feature.