# Reloading an edited, closed question causes the 'closed' label to be missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, live-refresh

When a closed question is edited, and I click the *This question has been edited. Click here to reload* link, the **[closed]** suffix will be missing from the title.

Comment: Until you refresh the page?

Comment: @Bart: Exactly.

Comment: Apparently when they fulfilled [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130447), they forgot to check closed status with it.

Answer (score 2):

Good catch - the status of a question (closed or otherwise) will be shown with the closed label after a refresh.  This will be in the next build.