# Close reason and duplicate question list being removed when loading edits to answers on closed question

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, live-refresh

I opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143492/what-is-it-in-javascript) which has been closed as a duplicate. Prior to being closed it had received a single answer. After I had loaded the page an edit was made to that answer, resulting in the notification/live refresh link ("an edit has been made to this answer; click here to refresh") appearing at the top of the answer.

Upon clicking on the link to refresh the answer, the answer was updated (as expected) but the box containing the list of duplicate questions ("This question already has an answer here:") and the close reason were removed from the page.

Comment: This bug [has been reported before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141941/reloading-an-edited-closed-question-causes-the-closed-label-to-be-missing) but should have been fixed.

Comment: @CodyGray Looks to be a slightly different issue; the title of the question is fine after the reload (it still contains the [duplicate] label), it's the other parts that are added to closed questions that are disappearing now.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I posted the wrong link. I was thinking of the question Animuson found. Glad he's here to pick up my slack. :-)