# Close reason disappears when edited answer is reloaded

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions

A little hard to reproduce, but here's what happens:

- A question is closed which has an answer (might need to have only one answer)
- That answer is edited, `[an edit has been made to this post, click to reload]` appears
- Clicking that message makes the close reason disappear

Here's a video: http://www.screenr.com/3NmH

At first I though "Holy crap, that was reopened fast", then I reloaded the whole page and the close message was back. In fact, I think this bug has been around for quite some time.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141941/reloading-an-edited-closed-question-causes-the-closed-label-to-be-missing

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192588/close-reason-and-duplicate-question-list-being-removed-when-loading-edits-to-ans?rq=1

Comment: There are a lot of posts like this that are `[status-completed]` supposedly, so I don't know where this issue stands.