# Refreshing a post via the "change" notice causes the question notice to disappear

Tags: bug, status-completed, post-notices, migration-notice

I noticed a minor bug today. If a question has a post notice, that notice disappears if any of the answers (or the question itself) are refreshed. By "refreshed" I mean by clicking on the little gray bar at the top of the post that says something like "this post has changed... click this to refresh it".

Here is sample post, with the notice:

---

[image: post notice]

---

And this is what happened when I refreshed the answer post:

---

[image: notice gone]

---

I noticed this on MSO just shortly prior; I also noticed this behavior on SO with a question close notice (not 100% sure on the latter though).

I should add that the notice disappearing is temporary. It comes back when the entire page is reloaded (e.g., pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Comment: AJAX does not load those things, only the new title and body, maybe tags. And worth to mention, for long years it didn't even load the title, [until reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130577/152859).

Comment: I guess I would wonder why this would happen if an answer is being reloaded. I suppose they could share the same div at some level, but it doesn't quite make sense to reload both the question and answer. I only have access to my tablet, otherwise I'd debug it further.